# Corte de control c#

Tags: c#

[1]Tengo que realizar un corte de control y mostrarlo en un listbox por marca de los siguientes datos

```
FORD;KA;3
FORD;FIESTA;5
FORD;MONDEO,8
RENAULT;DUSTER;7
RENAULT;SANDERO;7
VOLKSWAGEN;SURAN;6
```

al ejecutar el codigo siguiente en mi listbox aparece solo el primer registro. la operacion funciona pero no se como hacer para que cambie de linea

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("D:\CARPETA DE GABI\PROGRAMACION l\Practica General Final\Parcial Final P1\VentaAutos.txt");

```
       string[] vector = new string[0];
       string marca = String.Empty;
       

       int ventasxmarca = 0;
       int salir = 0;

       vector = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');

       while (salir == 0)
       {
           marca = vector[0];
           ventasxmarca = 0;



           Listado.Items.Add(String.Format("Marca {0}", marca));


           while (salir == 0 && marca == vector[0])
           {

               ventasxmarca += int.Parse(vector[2]);


               if (reader.Peek() == -1)
               {
                   Listado.Items.Add(String.Format("Modelo: {0} \t Ventas: {1}", vector[1], vector[2]));
                   salir++;
               }
               else
               {

                   Listado.Items.Add(String.Format("Modelo: {0} \t Ventas: {1}", vector[1], vector[2]));
                   reader.ReadLine().Split(';');
               }

               Listado.Items.Add(String.Format("Total de ventas por marca: {0}", ventasxmarca));
           }
           
       }
       reader.Close();
```

Comment: Buenas, Gabriel, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado dados esos datos que indicas? ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora para conseguir ese resultado?

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Y cual es el problema??? suena a un ejercicio muy bonito, donde lo ultimo que deberias hacer es mostrar el resultado...

Comment: el problema me surge al momentos de mostrar el listbox
me aparece vacio
mi primer codigo funcionaba pero no realizaba el corte en ningun momento 
se quedaba en el primer registro

Comment: ¿Qué repámpanos es un "*corte de control*"?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no porfa no digas eso.. es algo muy comun entre nosotros los mayores de 40 

Comment: Si sabes usar diccionarios, te diria que la version moderna (porque si no, deberias si o si ordenar la entrada) seria que agregaras la marca a un diccionario y solo sumaras ahi la cantidad, y luego al terminar muestres en el listbox el diccionario... pero claro, eso depende de que te pidieron realmente en el ejercicio. Si tenias que hacer cortes de control reales, a la antigua, tenes que ir sumando hasta que cambies de grupo, ahi mostrar el grupo que termino y empezar a sumar de vuelta

Comment: y claro.. ORDENAR ANTES...

Comment: Cual sería el resultado esperado?